# How to return JSON format from urlopen() response?

Tags: python, urllib

I am newbie to python and when trying such a code, I got weird characters.

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen(
        "http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=MSFT&region=1&lang=en") \
            as response:
    source = response.read()
    print(source)
```

I expect the response to be JSON format but I got weird response like this:

[image]

Comment: What you're seeing there is a byte array. You can tell by the 'b' preceding the string. You'll want to decode these bytes into characters, and to do so you need to know what character encoding is being used. A good guess would be response.decode("utf-8").

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried the line you referred `response.decode("utf-8")` before the line `source = response.read()` but seems not to work and I got errors.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have used this line `source=source.decode("utf-8")` and this solved the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I already posted the problem and the response I received. I did know now that this is an array of bytes and the problem solved after using the decode method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the expected output using the following with [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/):

```
import requests

url = 'http://d.yimg.com/autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=MSFT&region=1&lang=en'

rsp = requests.get(url)
print(rsp.json())
```

Comment: I got the expected result just copy and pasting the code in the question. @YasserKhalil, what version of Python are you using?

Comment: I am using Anaconda3